# C++ Application POST request doesn't work while GET request is fine

Tags: php, http, request, hosting

This code works when i call the script from QT Application

```
<?php
include_once("_config.php");

$api = $_GET['api'];

echo $api;?>
```

Code to call the script

```
QUrl url(path + "/_getcl.php?api=testing");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

networkManager->get(request, params.query().toUtf8());
```

But when i try with POST request, the $_POST['api'] line returns nothing.

```
<?php
include_once("_config.php");

$api = $_POST['api'];

echo $api;?>
```

Code to call the POST request script

```
QUrl url(path + "/_getcl.php");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QUrlQuery params;
params.addQueryItem("api", "testing");
networkClients->post(request, params.query().toUtf8());
```

These lines was working on my old hosting service. I bought a new hosting on hostinger then moved to it.

Comment: Try sending this `POST` request using `curl` or any api testing tool like `postman`, if you get the same result then the problem is with your hosting service, not `Qt` related problem.

Comment: I know that problem is with my hosting service. Because it was working on my previous hosting service. But i don't know what causes that.

Comment: This not `qt` or `C++` related question!